# SOLR indexing Error: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException

Tags: indexing, solr

I am getting an issue while indexing data in SOLR. I am using SOLR 7.3. Previously when I was indexing the data, there is no issue with that. But this time I am facing below issue:

> org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Exception writing document id 484841_DC to the index; possible analysis error.
>       at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:233)
>       at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:67)
>       at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
>       at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:950)
>       at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1163)
>       at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:633)
>       at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessorFactory$LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:103)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter.upload(SolrWriter.java:80)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler$1.upload(DataImportHandler.java:257)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:527)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:415)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:330)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:233)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:424)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:483)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.lambda$runAsync$0(DataImporter.java:466)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@23abff8e rejected from java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@43f6e29f[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 5906]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2063)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:830)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:326)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:533)
>       at org.apache.solr.update.CommitTracker._scheduleCommitWithin(CommitTracker.java:151)
>       at org.apache.solr.update.CommitTracker._scheduleCommitWithinIfNeeded(CommitTracker.java:119)
>       at org.apache.solr.update.CommitTracker.addedDocument(CommitTracker.java:170)
>       at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc0(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:279)
>       at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:221)

After googling I found that I need to use analysis tab to debug the issue by input each value according to its column in SOLR. But no issue found there.

Please help me in resolving the issue.

Comment: Is this the complete stacktrace, or are there multiple levels of exceptions?

Comment: This is the complete stacktrace of an indexing.